# Openstack can not delete instance from dashboard

Tags: openstack

There are 66 instances in Openstack Havana. I think these instances are zombies instance. Dashboard displays `Terminate Success info` when I click `Terminate Instance`. But the instance still exists on dashboard and its status is `Running`. I have already kill all `qemu-kvm` program on server.

In Mysql, database `nova` remains a lot of data. I don't know where to start to delete these data. Could someone give me some advice ?? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did this in the **Icehouse** release of OpenStack, maybe you can map this to the Havana release:

1. log into the database (you should see `> mysql` in your console)
2. select the nova database:

   `use nova;`
3. mark the rows in table *instances* as deleted (that's a "soft-delete"):

   `update instances set deleted_at = updated_at, deleted = id, power_state = 0, vm_state = "deleted", terminated_at = updated_at, root_device_name = NULL, task_state = NULL where deleted = 0;`

   <-- That 'deletes' **ALL** your instances! Use `show columns from instances;` if you want to choose another column(s) for your *where-clause*.
4. update the cache in table *instance_info_caches* appropriately:

   `update instance_info_caches set deleted_at = updated_at, deleted = id where deleted = 0;`
5. update the *fixed_ips* table:

   `update fixed_ips set instance_id = NULL, allocated = 0, virtual_interface_id = NULL where deleted = 0;`

**Note:** If the column *deleted* contains a value **not equal to zero**, then this seems to be the way to say *this row is supposed to be deleted*. When I delete an instance via API, OpenStack seems to choose the *id* as value for *deleted*.

**Source**: http://www.databaseskill.com/4605135/

Answer (score 4):

You can manually reset the VM state and delete using the following commands

```
$ nova reset-state c6bbbf26-b40a-47e7-8d5c-eb17bf65c485
$ nova delete c6bbbf26-b40a-47e7-8d5c-eb17bf65c485
```

http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide-cloud/content//reset-state.html

Answer (score 0):

How to revert back soft-delete? 
I have used below command:

```
update instances set deleted_at = updated_at, deleted = id, power_state = 0, vm_state = "deleted", terminated_at = updated_at, root_device_name = NULL, task_state = NULL where deleted = 0;
```